# Getting ray using gluUnProject or inverted MVP matrix

Tags: opengl, c++, raycasting, perspective, raytracing

I've read a lot of topics here, on SO, opengl.org etc.
Example how gluUnProject should work (from NeHe tutorial):

```
winX = (float)x;
winY = (float)viewport[3] - (float)y;
glReadPixels( x, int(winY), 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &winZ );
gluUnProject( winX, winY, winZ, modelview, projection, viewport, &posX, &posY, &posZ);
```

The problem is that `gluUnProject` returns mostly zeros, if not zeros then it returns Camera position in World Coords. Value `winZ` I'm getting from `glReadPixels` is always correct, if I scale it like below:

`float z_distance = ProjectionMatrix[14] / (winZ * -2.0 + 1.0 - ProjectionMatrix[10]);`

I get distance between near plane and parallel plane that contains mouse click point. Look at the sample below:

```
gluUnProject( winX, winY, -1, modelview, projection, viewport, &posX1, &posY1, &posZ1);
gluUnProject( winX, winY, 0, modelview, projection, viewport, &posX2, &posY2, &posZ2);
gluUnProject( winX, winY, 1, modelview, projection, viewport, &posX3, &posY3, &posZ3);
gluUnProject( winX, winY, winZ, modelview, projection, viewport, &posX4, &posY4, &posZ4);
```

The result is always the same `(posX1,posY1,posZ1)=(posX2,posY2,posZ2)=(posX3,posY3,posZ3)=(posX4,posY4,posZ4)` and is either `(0,0,0)` or `(Camera-Position.x,Camera-Position.y,Camera-Position.z)`

After `gluUnProject` I tried to do it manually:

```
float NDC_x = 2.0f * winX / Width - 1.0f;
float NDC_y = 1.0f - 2.0f * winY / Height;
float winZ = 0;
glReadPixels(winX, (Height - winY), 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &winZ);
vec4 point1 = inverse(ViewProjectionMatrix) * vec4(NDC_x, NDC_y, winZ, 1.0f);
vec4 point2 = inverse(ViewProjectionMatrix) * vec4(NDC_x, NDC_y, -1.0f, 1.0f);
vec4 point3 = inverse(ViewProjectionMatrix) * vec4(NDC_x, NDC_y, 0.0f, 1.0f);
vec4 point4 = inverse(ViewProjectionMatrix) * vec4(NDC_x, NDC_y, 1.0f, 1.0f);
```

Now all points coordinates are different and never zeros but some values, seems like real ones but I don't know how to handle it or I missed something.

BTW I used different approach to get ray (using angles) and it works perfectly. Check [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/107900/cursor-position-to-a-3d-ray-using-angles).

Q1: Any suggestions what's wrong with `gluUnProject` ?

Q2: What is my mistake in manual implementation?

I thought that I messed with row\column-major format, but transposition of matrices had no effect. I read\write matrices as column-major format so last column is `(ViewMatrix[12], ViewMatrix[13], ViewMatrix[14], ViewMatrix[15])`

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, we should convert winX and winY values in pixels to Normalized Device Coordinates.

To get world coordinates from pixel position on screen we should multiply inverse ViewProjection matrix by clip space `vec3(NDC_x, NDC_y, some_z, 1.0f)`
Actually every pixel on screen corresponds to line in world space. So the question is what `some_z` value to use. But no matter what values we will use - final points will always be laying on our ray.

Tricky part is to correctly use received values. Let's look at four possible situations I've mentioned in opening post:

```
float NDC_x = 2.0f * winX / Width - 1.0f;
float NDC_y = 1.0f - 2.0f * winY / Height;
float winZ = 0;
glReadPixels(winX, (Height - winY), 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &winZ);
vec4 point1 = inverse(ViewProjectionMatrix) * vec4(NDC_x, NDC_y, winZ, 1.0f);
vec4 point2 = inverse(ViewProjectionMatrix) * vec4(NDC_x, NDC_y, -1.0f, 1.0f);
vec4 point3 = inverse(ViewProjectionMatrix) * vec4(NDC_x, NDC_y, 0.0f, 1.0f);
vec4 point4 = inverse(ViewProjectionMatrix) * vec4(NDC_x, NDC_y, 1.0f, 1.0f);
```

Now we need to do perspective division (this part that is missing very often).

Note: code below uses 'point' with no numeration because its the same for any case.

```
point /= point.w; //perspective division for chosen point
vec3 RayDirection = vec3(point.x, point.y, point.z) - Camera->Position; 
 //subtracting  camera position from 'point' coordinates gives as ray direction, length 
 //depends on `z-value` used: '1.0f' gives us ray that stops on far plane, '0.0f' - ray 
 //will stop at near plane, all negative values return point between camera and near plane,
 //using value from glReadPixels(from 0 to 1) returns point between near and far plane
ScaledRay = RayDirection * scale; //scale original ray in 'scale' times
NormalizedRay = normalize(ScaledRay); //normalizing ray length to 1, we can normalize first
                //and then scale to whatever length we want(for example range of shooting)
RayEndPoint = NormalizedRay + Camera->Position; //adding Camera position gives endpoint
```

Now when we know how to handle values - same goes for `gluUnProject`:

```
GLint vp[4];
glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, vp);
GLdouble wx = 0, wy = 0, wz = 0;
gluUnProject(winX, (vp[3] - winY), 0, mvmatrix, projmatrix, vp, &wx, &wy, &wz);
vec3 RayEndpoint = vec3((float)wx, (float)wy, (float)wz);
vec3 RayDirection = RayEndpoint - Camera->Position; 
vec3 ScaledRay = RayDirection * Scale;
vec3 NormalizedRay = normalize(ScaledRay);
RayEndPoint = NormalizedRay + Camera->Position;
```

Note: gluUnProject is unstable for me - mostly it returns zeros or #INF, but once per 10 launches of `exe` it works flawlessly (I meant I never change `exe` but just starting it again and again).